# chrome.tabs.query not executing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

My js code just doesnt execute the chrome.tabs.query line. When I went through it stepwise over the debugger it will immediately go to the next executing statement ie return. I looked this up and I understand that this is an asynchronous call but even after waiting the debugger or alert inside the chrome.tabs.query just wouldn't hit. Please help.

```
/*
Given the name of a beast, get the URL to the corresponding image.
*/
debugger;
function beastNameToURL(beastName) {
  switch (beastName) {
    case "Save Session":
      debugger;
      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        debugger;
        alert("1");

        tabs.forEach(function(tab){
          unsafeWindow.console.log("helllllloooooooooooooooooo");
          unsafeWindow.console.log(tab.url);
        });

        for (var tab of tabs) {
          if (tab.active) {
            console.log(tab.url);
          }
        }
    });

        return;
    case "Load Session":
    debugger;
      return chrome.extension.getURL("beasts/snake.jpg");
    case "Turtle":
      return chrome.extension.getURL("beasts/turtle.jpg");
  }
}

/*
Listen for clicks in the popup.

If the click is not on one of the beasts, return early.

Otherwise, the text content of the node is the name of the beast we want.

Inject the "beastify.js" content script in the active tab.

Then get the active tab and send "beastify.js" a message
containing the URL to the chosen beast's image.
*/
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  if (!e.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
    return;
  }


  var chosenBeast = e.target.textContent;
  var chosenBeastURL = beastNameToURL(chosenBeast);

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "/content_scripts/beastify.js"
  });

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {beastURL: chosenBeastURL});
  });

});
```

I have also given permissions to tabs in the manifest.

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Session",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Adds a browser action icon to the toolbar. Click the button to choose a beast. The active tab's body content is then replaced with a picture of the chosen beast. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#beastify",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/beasts-48.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "beastify@mozilla.org",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/beasts-32.png",
    "default_title": "Session",
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_beast.html"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "beasts/frog.jpg",
    "beasts/turtle.jpg",
    "beasts/snake.jpg"
  ]

}
```